Unable to access Team Tab in Excel
When trying to integrate Microsoft Excel with Azure DevOps I need to access the Team tab in Excel to create a list as the first step to import my spreadsheet into DevOps. Upon trying to do this, I am unable to see this Team Tab.
So far, I have tried to find it in my Add Ins which has failed.
If anyone would be able to help that would be great, Thanks!
I was expecting to see the correct Add In to bring the Teams tab into my ribbon, but I could not find this.

Did you check these solutions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/tfs-office-integration-issues?view=azure-devops

Hi @HarrisonPrangnell100, what's the latest state of the issue? Have you installed required software and check the official troubleshooting doc?

Connection from an Excel to an Azure Boards project requires the following software.

Microsoft Excel 2010 or later
Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019. The only way to get the Azure DevOps Office Integration plug-in is by installing one of the latest editions of Visual Studio or the Azure DevOps Office Integration installer.
Visual Studio (at least VS 2015.1 or later version) or Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2015 Update 2 or later version.

To install Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019 from VS, open your VS Installer, modify your VS, search "Azure DevOps Office Integration" from Individual components and install it.

If you still can't see the Team tab in Excel, see Resolve Azure DevOps Office integration issues as mentioned by @Shamrai Aleksander.
Note: macOS isn't supported. Even if you've installed Visual Studio for Mac, connection to Azure DevOps from Excel or other Office client isn't supported.
